# Discord.js v12 server member count

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

(Welcome command using canvas)

How could I fetch the server member count as soon as someone joins??

Because I use that line of code

```
 const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("843190900930510869");
    let image = await welcomeCanvas
      .setUsername(member.user.tag)
      .setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)
      .setMemberCount(guild.memberCount) //this line
    etc...
```

And well, it just doesn't send the image..

Error:

> (node:6387) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of undefined
> at GuildMemberAddListener.exec (/app/listeners/guildMemberAdd.js:100:29)
> (node:6387) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:6387) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `guild`? Are you sure the snowflake is a guild's ID? Is the bot is a member of the guild with the ID of `843190900930510869`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros 

1. I forgot how to do that
2. Yes it is a guild ID
3. The bot is in the guild

Comment: Have you tried using [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead of `get()`? It would look like this `const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("843190900930510869");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `client.on('guildMemberAdd', () => {})` will return a GuildMember object. Simply use this GuildMember object to get the guild they entered `GuildMember.guild` then check if that guild is available to the client using `guild.available`. If it is available you can access all the properties on that guild including the `guild.memberCount` property.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  const guild = member.guild
  if (!guild.available) return console.error('Uh Oh Stinky...')
  const guildMemberCount = guild.memberCount
  console.log(guildMemberCount)
})
```